# Python function returning None when trying to display dataframe

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a url from bbc recipe and then get the information and then put it into a dataframe. When I am trying to run the function I made The result I am getting is 'None' and I am unsure why because it worked before I tried to organise them into a function

```
columns_name=['title', 'total_time', 'image', 'ingredients', 'rating_val', 
'rating_count',
'category', 'cuisine', 'diet', 'vegan', 'vegetarian', 'url']
url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/avocado_pasta_with_peas_31700'

def print_dataframe(df):
  return df

def insert_df(name,totalTime,image,rating_count,rating_value,Category,Ingredients,diet,vegan,vegetarian,url,df):
  new_row = {'name':name,'totalTime':totalTime,'image':image,'rating_count':rating_count,'rating_value':rating_value,'Category':Category,'Ingredients':Ingredients,'diet':diet,'vegan':vegan,'vegetarian':vegetarian,'url':url}
  df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

def collect_page_data(url,columns_name):
  df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns_name)

  page = requests.get(url)
  page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')



  res = page_soup.find("script", {"type":
  "application/ld+json"})

  data = json.loads(res.text)

  name = data['author']['name']

  image= data['image']
  rating_count = data['aggregateRating']['ratingCount'] 
  rating_value = data['aggregateRating']['ratingValue']
  Category = data['recipeCategory']
  Ingredients = data['recipeIngredient']
  diet = data['suitableForDiet'][1]
  vegan = data['suitableForDiet'][2]
  vegetarian = data['suitableForDiet'][3]
  prepTime = data['prepTime']
  cookTime = data['cookTime']

  l = ['P','T','M']
  for i in l:
   prepTime = prepTime.replace(i,"")
   cookTime = cookTime.replace(i,"")
  totalTime = int(prepTime) + int(cookTime)
  insert_df(name,totalTime,image,rating_count,rating_value,Category,Ingredients,diet,vegan,vegetarian,url,df)
    
  print_dataframe(df)

print(collect_page_data(url,columns_name))
```

Comment: `collect_page_data` doesn't return anything, so Python makes it return `None`. Note that calling `print_dataframe` doesn't return the dataframe from `collect_page_data`.

Comment: @ForceBru what do I do to fix this issue?

Comment: You should return the dataframe from `collect_page_data`

Comment: @ForceBru I put ' return df' in collect_page_data and I am now getting 'empty dataframe' is there a problem with the insert function?

Comment: Yep: `df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)` simply creates a new local variable called `df` and immediately abandons it. `append` returns a new dataframe, so the original `df` is never modified.

Comment: @ForceBru so should I do 'new_df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)' and then return this. How do I update the df permanently?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242403/discussion-between-joshcampbell7-and-forcebru).

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with two `return`.

**First:**

In `insert_df()` you use

```
df = df.append(...)
```

which create local `df` inside `insert_df()` - it doesn't change external `df`

You should rather use `return` and use

```
return df.append(...)
```

and execute function as

```
df = insert_df()
```

**Second():**

At the end of `collect_page_data()` you run

```
print_dataframe(df)
```

which get `df` and only returns it back. It can't get it back from `collect_page_data()

At the end of `collect_page_data()` you should run

```
return df
```

---

And this is full code:

I my version of `BeautifulSoup` I had to use `res.string` instead of `res.text` to get text.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

# --- functions ---

def insert_df(name, totalTime, image, rating_count, rating_value, Category, Ingredients, diet, vegan, vegetarian, url, df):
    new_row = {'name':name,'totalTime':totalTime,'image':image,'rating_count':rating_count,'rating_value':rating_value,'Category':Category,'Ingredients':Ingredients,'diet':diet,'vegan':vegan,'vegetarian':vegetarian,'url':url}
    return df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

def collect_page_data(url, columns_name):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns_name)

    page = requests.get(url)
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    
    res = page_soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"})
    
    #data = json.loads(res.text)
    data = json.loads(res.string)
    
    name = data['author']['name']
    
    image= data['image']
    rating_count = data['aggregateRating']['ratingCount'] 
    rating_value = data['aggregateRating']['ratingValue']
    Category = data['recipeCategory']
    Ingredients = data['recipeIngredient']
    diet = data['suitableForDiet'][1]
    vegan = data['suitableForDiet'][2]
    vegetarian = data['suitableForDiet'][3]
    prepTime = data['prepTime']
    cookTime = data['cookTime']
    
    l = ['P','T','M']
    for i in l:
        prepTime = prepTime.replace(i, "")
        cookTime = cookTime.replace(i, "")
        
    totalTime = int(prepTime) + int(cookTime)
    
    df = insert_df(name, totalTime, image, rating_count, rating_value, Category, Ingredients, diet, vegan, vegetarian, url, df)
        
    return df

# --- main ---

columns_name = [
    'title', 'total_time', 'image', 'ingredients', 'rating_val', 
    'rating_count', 'category', 'cuisine', 'diet', 'vegan', 'vegetarian', 'url'
]

url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/avocado_pasta_with_peas_31700'

df = collect_page_data(url, columns_name)

print(df.iloc[0])
```

Result:

(I get only first row - so I have `Series` which displays data as column)

```
title                                                         NaN
total_time                                                    NaN
image           [https://food-images.files.bbci.co.uk/food/rec...
ingredients                                                   NaN
rating_val                                                    NaN
rating_count                                                   22
category                                                      NaN
cuisine                                                       NaN
diet                             http://schema.org/LowCalorieDiet
vegan                                 http://schema.org/VeganDiet
vegetarian                       http://schema.org/VegetarianDiet
url             https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/avocado_pas...
Category                                              Main course
Ingredients     [375g/13oz pasta, such as penne or fusilli, 1 ...
name                                               Nadiya Hussain
rating_value                                             4.363636
totalTime                                                    40.0
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

---

**EDIT:**

As for me `insert_df()` is totaly useless and you could run its code directly in `collect_page_data()`. It could create more readable code.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

# --- functions ---

def collect_page_data(url, columns_name):

    # --- scraping ---
    
    page = requests.get(url)
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    
    res = page_soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"})

    #data = json.loads(res.text)
    data = json.loads(res.string)  # 
    
    prep_time = data['prepTime']
    cook_time = data['cookTime']
    
    for char in ['P', 'T', 'M']:
        prep_time = prep_time.replace(char, "")
        cook_time = cook_time.replace(char, "")
        
    total_time = int(prep_time) + int(cook_time)

    # --- dataframe ---
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns_name)
    
    df = df.append({
        'name': data['author']['name'],
        'total_time': total_time,
        'image': data['image'],
        'rating_count': data['aggregateRating']['ratingCount'],
        'rating_value': data['aggregateRating']['ratingValue'],
        'category': data['recipeCategory'],
        'ingredients': data['recipeIngredient'],
        'diet': data['suitableForDiet'][1],
        'vegan': data['suitableForDiet'][2],
        'vegetarian': data['suitableForDiet'][3],
        'url': url
    }, ignore_index=True)
        
    return df

# --- main ---

columns_name = [
    'title', 'name', 'total_time', 'image',
    'ingredients', 'rating_value', 'rating_count',
    'category', 'cuisine', 'diet', 'vegan', 'vegetarian', 'url'
]

url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/avocado_pasta_with_peas_31700'

df = collect_page_data(url, columns_name)

print(df.iloc[0])
```